# HybridIgniter Uncaught exception

Tags: php, codeigniter, hybridauth

I'm using HybridIgniter (HybridAuth for Codeigniter). If I try to login with Facebook and then I deny to approve the app, I receive the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Authentification failed! The user denied your request.' in /usr/local/psa/home/vhosts/whatabeer.com/httpdocs/application_cdb/website/third_party/hybridauth/Hybrid/Providers/Facebook.php:80 Stack trace: #0 /usr/local/psa/home/vhosts/whatabeer.com/httpdocs/application_cdb/website/third_party/hybridauth/Hybrid/Endpoint.php(175): Hybrid_Providers_Facebook->loginFinish() #1 /usr/local/psa/home/vhosts/whatabeer.com/httpdocs/application_cdb/website/third_party/hybridauth/Hybrid/Endpoint.php(56): Hybrid_Endpoint::processAuthDone() #2 /usr/local/psa/home/vhosts/whatabeer.com/httpdocs/application_cdb/website/third_party/hybridauth/index.php(15): Hybrid_Endpoint::process() #3 /usr/local/psa/home/vhosts/whatabeer.com/httpdocs/application_cdb/website/modules/hauth/controllers/hauth.php(254): require_once('/usr/local/psa/...') #4 [internal function]: HAuth->endpoint() #5 /usr/local/psa/home/vhosts/whatabeer.com/httpdocs/system_cdb/core/CodeIgniter.php(359): call_user_func_array( in /usr/local/psa/home/vhosts/whatabeer.com/httpdocs/application_cdb/website/third_party/hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php on line 153
```

I'm using Codeigniter 2.1.4 with HMVC and HybridAuth 2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

HybridAuth docs says it is expected behavior (http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/Errors_and_Exceptions_Handling.html):

Since 2.0 HybridAuth work mostly on exceptions, just throw your code inside an try{} catch(Exception $e){} block and that is it.